# C++ Sort a pointer array in asscending order

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, bubble-sort

I have this function where 2 vectors get compared with each other and the program finds the sum of squared difference from the vector.

```
    double Search::NNS(vector<vector<double>> bb, vector<vector<double>> aa)
    {
        int M = 768; int N = 1024;
        int R = 49; int C = 36;
        //double SSD[] = MainVectorBlock[] - WallyVector[];
        //double SSD[] = SSD[] * SSD[];
        //sum = sum + SSD[];

    vector<vector<double>> &MainIMG = bb;
    vector<vector<double>> &WallyIMG = aa;
    double *SSD = new double[R*C];
    double sum = 0;


    for (int bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R)
        for (int by = 0; by < N; by += C)
        {
            Compare = new double*[R];
            for (int x = 0; ((x < R) && ((bx + x) < M)); ++x)
            {
                Compare[x] = new double[R];
                for (int y = 0; ((y < C) && ((by + y) < N)); ++y)
                {
                    if ((bx + x) >= M)
                    {
                        cout << Compare[bx + x] << Compare[by + y] << " ";

                    }

                    //cout << MainIMG[bx + x][by + y] << " ";
                    Compare[x][y] = MainIMG[bx + x][by + y] - WallyIMG[x][y];
                    Compare[x][y] = Compare[x][y] * Compare[x][y];
                    //sum += Compare[x][y];
                    SSD[R*C] += Compare[x][y];
                    //SSD[R*C] = sum;
                    //cout << Compare[x][y] << " ";
                }

            }
            //cout << "\n\n\n" << endl;
            //cout << sum << endl;
            //cout << SSD[R*C] << "\t" << sum << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < R*C; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < R*C; j++)
                {
                    if (SSD[i] > SSD[j])
                    {
                        int temp = SSD[i];
                        SSD[i] = SSD[j];
                        SSD[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    for (int a = 0; a < R*C; a++)
    {
        cout << SSD[a] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can display all of the sum of squared difference values, however when I try to sort the values in ascending order, I keep on getting this value -6.27744e+66.
I have tried to change the loop and place it throughout the main for-loop but I still keep on getting that value.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: -6.27744e+66 looks like an uninitialised floating point double to me. Are you sure you are always reading elements within the bounds of the array?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have used the debugger but I still cannot figure out why this is happening

Comment: @MR1 `double *SSD = new double[R*C];` -- Why are you using `new[]` when you could just use `std::vector<double> SSD(R *C);`?  It makes no sense to use `vector` in one place, and refuse to use it in another.

Comment: @MR1 Well, if you're already using the debugger, what were your observations on the variable changes?

Comment: @MR1 -- Also, you have a memory leak of huge proportions here: `Compare = new double*[R];`.  Again, why not `std::vector<std::vector<double>> Compare(R, std::vector<double>(R));` and forego all of the `new[]` stuff?

Comment: `SSD[R*C] += Compare[x][y];` -- This  is also a memory overwrite.  You are writing one past the end of the array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi Paul, I'm am changing the code to how you have said, if i change the 'SSD[R*C] += Compare[x][y]', how will I be able to store the sum of squared difference values.

Comment: @MR1 I posted an answer to address the general issues, and frankly your program should have not gone past the `SSD[R*C] += ...` line, as anything after that is undefined behavior.  You'll have to figure out what element of SSD you are trying to sum up -- that's your homework -- I gave you a fighting chance with my answer below in solving this basic issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
double *SSD = new double[R*C];
```

You have allocated memory but never initialized it to some value. Then you have used it directly:

```
SSD[R*C] += Compare[x][y];
```

initialize all the items of `SSD` to `0` before start adding values to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. You're passing 2D vectors by value to the `NNS` function, when they should be passed by `const` reference.
2. You are creating memory leaks within the nested `for` loop.
3. You are writing one past the end of the array `SSD` in the sum calculation.
4. Your SSD array was not initialized to 0.

Here is a version of your function that does not have memory leaks, and will allow *you* to address item 3) above.  Granted this can be improved, but it does not have the issues mentioned above.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

double Search::NNS(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& bb, 
                   const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& aa)
{
    int M = 768; int N = 1024;
    int R = 49; int C = 36;
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &MainIMG = bb;
    const std::vector<std::vector<double>> &WallyIMG = aa;
    std::vector<double> SSD(R * C);
    double sum = 0;

    for (int bx = 0; bx < M; bx += R)
    {
        for (int by = 0; by < N; by += C)
        {
            std::vector<std::vector<double>> Compare(R, std::vector<double>(R));
            for (int x = 0; ((x < R) && ((bx + x) < M)); ++x)
            {
                for (int y = 0; ((y < C) && ((by + y) < N)); ++y)
                {
                    Compare[x][y] = MainIMG[bx + x][by + y] - WallyIMG[x][y];
                    Compare[x][y] = Compare[x][y] * Compare[x][y];
                    SSD.at(R*C) += Compare[x][y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::sort(SSD.begin(), SSD.end());
    for (int a = 0; a < R*C; a++)
        std::cout << SSD[a] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Issue 1) is addressed by passing the `vector`s by const reference.  Passing the vector's by value as your original code was doing incurs an unnecessary copy.

Issue 2) is addressed by using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.  There are now no memory leaks.

Issue 3) is **not** addressed directly.  What was done was to use `std::vector::at()` to demonstrate that there is an out of bounds condition occurring.  A `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown if you're going out of bounds when `at()` is used, showing there is an error in your array accesses.  Your code would have stopped as soon as that line was executed.  Here is where I leave it to you to solve the boundary condition.

You may also want to use `at()` on the `Compare` vector to ensure you're not going out-of-bounds there.  I am lazy and didn't want to do the calculation in my head, but whenever you have `for` loop conditions that do not use the `vector::size()` as a limiting condition and instead, a calculation is used to determine how far to loop, it looks suspicious and is a candidate for an out-of-bounds situation to occur.

Also, when you used `new[]`, there is no guarantee you will get this error, and from what you've stated, you didn't get an indication you were doing something wrong.  Using `std::vector` gives you a chance to check boundary conditions using `at()`.

Issue 4) is addressed by using `std::vector<double>`, as by default, the vector will initialize the contents to 0.

Last, note the usage of `std::sort` to sort the range, and not the slow bubble sort.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the memory leaks, I will work on it. Cheers again